# дія до іменника ескалація — "ескалувати" чи "ескалювати"?

Tags: словотворення

в словниках присутнє слово іншомовного походження "ескалація", проте в жодному я не знайшов дієслова, що позначає цю дію. В англійській мові є "escalate", в російській "эскалировать". В українській це інтуїтивно могло б бути "ескалувати" як і більшість інших дієслів до іменнииків із закніченням "ація" (дотація – дотувати, культивація — культивувати). Проте складність в тому, що "ескалація" це єдине слово, що з незрозумілих причин закінчується саме на "лація", а не на "ляція" як всі інші із останньою літерою кореня "л" (напр. emulation — емул**я**ція, емул**ю**вати; modulation — модул**я**ція, модул**ю**вати; capitulation — капітул**я**ція, капітул**ю**вати), через що варіант "ескал**ю**вати" теж інтуїтивно видається припустимим.

Питання: як правильно і що є визначальним для утворення дієслова — літера "а" у слові ескалація або ж корінь, що закінчується на "л"

Comment: Раджу замінити на відповідне слово українською мовою згідно змісту. Наприклад, підвищення, покращення, підняття. Наведіть текст, будь ласка, де використовується це слово.

Answer (score 4):

У словниках дійсно мало інформації щодо цього слова, тому насмілюся озвучити свою думку з цього приводу, адже це слово постійно вживається принаймні у мене на роботі.

Я вважаю, що в даному випадку можна вдатися до аналогій. Наприклад, англійське слово `manipulate` перекладається на українську як `маніпулювати`. Тому особисто для мене природнім є перекласти `escalate` як `ескалювати`. Так само слово `escalation` я б переклав як `ескаляція`, аналогічно до того ж слова `маніпуляція`, а також `вентиляція`, `апеляція` (`апелювати`), `інсталяція` (`інсталювати`) тощо.

Answer (score 2):

По-перше, зазначу, що слова такого, здається, немає. Принаймні словники його не фіксують і на практиці воно майже не вживається. Те, що подібне слово є в англійській і російській, не означає, що воно має бути в українській. «Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки)» О. Кочерги і Є. Мейнаровича (2010) [перекладає](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=escalate) *escalate* як *ширити/розгортати/посилювати*; словник «ABBYY Lingvo Live» (імовірно, на базі словника В. Бусела) [перекладає](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/en-uk/escalate) *escalate* як *підніматися на ескалаторі / загострювати / ввергати / рости / збільшувати / підвищувати*.

Але якщо вже вводити неологізм (і я, власне, не маю нічого проти такого неологізму; можливо, потреба в ньому справді є; і наявність подібного слова в двох найуживаніших українцями іноземних мовах зробить упровадження такого неологізму цілком природним), то я би виходив з того, що слово *ескал**а́**ція* зафіксувалося в українській мові випадково (чи то під упливом російської, чи то через ще незавершену асиміляцію англійського слова), і утворював його від слова *ескал**я́**ція*. Зрештою, варіант *ескал**я́**ція* теж уживають; наприклад, газета [«Свобода»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%A8%D0%90)) (видає Український Народний Союз у США) майже послідовно (окрім одного вживання в № 8 від 20.02.2015) пише *ескал**я́**ція* (зокрема в [№ 5–7, 13–15, 22, 25, 31, 35, 36, 42, 47, 49 від 2015](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/view?q=aword,[word="[%D0%95%D0%B5]%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86.*"]); так пишуть і деякі інші джерела, що можна побачити в [Google Books](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F). Тому я писав би *ескал**ю**ва́ти*.

Утім, оскільки слово не зафіксоване, то Ви цілком можете писати й *ескал**у**ва́ти*. І так іноді пишуть, наприклад:

> …То коли переселяться в мирніший і спокійніший край, то знову ж таки разом із собою принесуть свої неспокої та немир'я, і так без кінця, бо вони ж постійно **ескалують** ці неспокій та немир'я по безмежних просторах (Євген Гуцало «Ментальність орди», 1995).
>
> ---
>
> Кампанія починалася з найкращими намірами (уникнути війни на виснаження, яку пам'ятали з окопів Першої світової), проте врешті саме на те й перетворилася і постійно **ескалувала**, аж доки не стала ненаситним звіром, якому вічно не вистачало людей, технологій, сировини — які, можливо, продуктивніше було б скерувати деінде, особливо в останні місяці — і звістувала апокаліптичні сценарії цілій Європі (Кейт Аткінсон «Руїни бога» у перекладі Ярослави Стріхи, 2017).

Update: Пишучи цю відповідь, я забув банально [подивитися в Google](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8). Слово таки вживається (хоч і нечасто), й узус очевидно за *ескал**у**ва́ти*. Імовірно, якщо Ви не прихильник писати *ескаляція*, *ескалятор* (і, можливо, навіть інші слова за якимось неофіційним правописом; а пишете *ескалація*, *ескалатор*, як більшість), то Вам усе-тики слід спинитися на варіанті, який мені особисто подобається менше, — *ескал**у**ва́ти*.

Comment: Згадана вами Свобода послуговує ся скипниківкою, не дивно, же там __ля__.

Comment: Погоджуюся з тим, що це слово не потрібне. Можна легко замінити на звичніший відповідник в українській мові згідно змісту. Перекладачі лише спрощують собі життя та не витрачають зайвий час на те, щоб підібрати правильне слово.

Comment: Якщо ви вважаєте це слово непотрібним, то підкажіть, будь ласка, його коректний переклад, бо я його використовую чи не щодня у сфері управління проектами (Project Management). І не у значенні підійматися на ескалаторі, а в значенні "to escalate an issue" https://mlpconsultants.com/escalations-are-an-essential-part-of-project-management/